# prevenção de erros de usuario, codigo em python

Tags: python

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]bom, eu tenho uns exercicios em python pois estou estudando, aprendi a formatar strings e usar as outras ferramentas, porem, nao consegui uma solucao para nao deixar o usuario errar enquanto executa o codigo, por exemplo, escrever umas string aonde devia ser um numero inteiro. a primeira parte do exercicio nao tem uma prevencao de erro do usuario, quando pergunto a idade da pessoa a cadastrar, nas outras partes o loop while consegue atender bem e nao deixa o usuario passar pra proxima etapa caso as informaçoes digitadas estejam incorretas. Se alguem tiver uma soluçao que possa me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
print(f'REGISTER A PERSON')
conts = 0
conta = 0
cont2 = 0

while True:
    print(f'---' * 10)
    age = int(input(f'Type a age: '))
    sex = ' '
    while sex not in 'MmFf':
        sex = str(input(f'Type a sex: [M/F] ')).strip().upper()[0]
        if age < 18:
            conta += 1
        if sex in 'M':
            conts += 1
        if sex in 'F':
            if age < 20:
                cont2 += 1
    q = ' '
    while q not in 'YyNn':
        q = str(input(f'Do you want to continue? [Y/N] ')).upper().split()[0]
    if q == 'N':
        break
print(f'The total number of people under 18 is {conta}')
print(f'The total number of man registered is {conts}')
print(f'The total number of womans under 20 years old is {cont2}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possível solução para o seu problema, seria criar uma função para tratar este caso.

Poderia ser implementando com um fluxo bem parecido com o que utiliza em sua função de ler o `gênero` ou pergunta se `quer continuar`.

```
def lerEntradaNumeroInteiro():
    while True:
        entrada = input('Digite uma idade: ')
        try:
            idade = int(entrada)
            return idade
        except ValueError:
            print('Não foi possível representar o valor "{}" para um número inteiro válido'.format(entrada))
```

Existem ainda alguns problemas ao utilizar esta abordagem pois será possível incluir valores negativos então é necessário tratar este caso também.

Depois eu seu código basta utilizar esta função:

```
#...
while True:
    print(f'---' * 10)
    age = lerEntradaNumeroInteiro()
    sex = ' '
    #resto do código
```